# .dSYM file for iOS release build (firemonkey)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I deployed my app and submitted to Apple store.  It was rejected and they said it crashed on launch.  In the Rad Studio deployment window a .dSYM file is shown and it has a weird Remote Path.  What is a .dSYM file for?  It seems .dSYM has to do with debugging - do i just leave it out?

It is the first file in the list below.

[image]

**UPDATE:** After getting squared away on how to make sure the .dSYM file is created (and where) I now have this deployment window below.  I'm still not sure about that Remote Path.  Does this mean the .dSYM will be installed on the device?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a .dSYM file for?

This is covered in Embarcadero's documentation:

[dSYM Debug File (*.dSYM)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DSYM_Debug_File)

> When you build a project for **iOS Device - 32 bit** or **iOS Device - 64 bit**, RAD Studio generates a dSYM debug file if:
>
> - In Delphi, you enable the **Debug information** option in `Project > Options > Delphi Compiler > Linking`.
> - In C++, you enable the **Full debug information** option in `Project > Options > C++ Linker`.
>
> Note: Packages (Delphi) do not generate dSYM debug files.
>
> When you build your project, your dSYM debug file is generated by default as `<project>.dsym` into `C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\<project>\<platform>\<build configuration>`.
>
> To change the output directory:
>
> - In Delphi, use the **Output directory** option in `Project > Options > Delphi Compiler`.
> - In C++, use the **Final output directory** option in `Project > Options > C++ (Shared Options)`.

You should keep a copy of the `.dsym` file for each version of your app that you submit to Apple's App Store.  If you get a crash report from Apple, the `.dsym` file for that version of the app is needed to "symbolicate" the crash report to help you debug the crash:

[Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

Comment: Thanks Remy, I surmise that the .dSYM file should not be deployed to the App Store in the release build of the app.  Using the info you provide above i've set the C++ Linker option under "Symbols that our runtime expects to be exported" setting "Inherit" to false.   I suppose i can also just deselect that .dSYM file in the deployment window.

Comment: Thank you for the information on what to do with the .dSYM file.

Comment: [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) discusses deployment of the `dsym` file

Comment: That Apple documentation shows the dsym being held back for crash diagnosis - not being one of the files i would deploy when i do a Release deployment from Rad Studio.  Thank you for your clarity.

Comment: ...and i need to make sure "Full debug information" under C++ Linker is set to true so i can have the dsym file ready if/when i get a crash.

Comment: @relayman357 "*If you are distributing your app via the App Store, or conducting a beta test using Test Flight, you will be given the option of including the dSYM file when uploading your archive to iTunes Connect. In the submission dialog, check “Include app symbols for your application…”. **Uploading your dSYM file is necessary to receive crash reports collected from TestFlight users and customers who have opted to share diagnostic data**.*"

Comment: Ok, that is remarkably important.  Bless you Remy.  Now i'm digging through the iOS 11.3 bug with Embarcadero( https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20303)

Comment: Also, under C++ Compiler (Project Options) must have debugging set to true.

Comment: Remy - I edited the post up top to show new image.  Please see question there.

Comment: And what is your question exactly? Are you questioning the use of `..\ ` in the path refers to? Or do you not understand what `$(PROJECTNAME)` refers to? Be more specific. If you include a file in the Deployment Manager, then yes, the file should be installed on the device. Did you test that before submitting to the App Store?

Comment: Based on your information i set a specific folder under C++ (Shared Options) in the Final output directory:  "T:\dSYM output\".  When i build the project, sure enough the .dSYM file shows up there.  Then when i go to deploy i see  "..\dSYM output\" with a Remote Path of ..\$(PROJECTNAME).app.dSYM\Contents\Resources\DWARF\ and i don't know how to interpret that.

Comment: Secondly, i don't know how to make sure the .dSYM file gets uploaded when i do "Application Loader" over on the mac with Xcode.  All i can select is the IPA file.  I can't see how to make sure the .dSYM got uploaded with the package.

Comment: Forgot to say, yes, app works fine on all tested devices.

Comment: 1.  So does "$(PROJECTNAME).app.dSYM\Contents\Resources\DWARF\" refer to a location on any device that installs my app from the store?  2.  So the .dSYM file gets put in that folder?